# How to print a list using splat-operator (*) without spaces

Tags: python, splat

I'm trying to understand splat-operators in python. I have a code:

```py
word = ['s', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w']
print(*word)
```

output:

```
s t a c k o v e r f l o w
```

I can't assign `*word` to some variable to check its type or smth else in debug. So I wounder which way `print()` gets the sequence of `*word` and if it's possible to print this word without spaces. Desirable output:

```
stackoverflow
```

Comment: `print(''.join(word))`?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I guess the question is confusing, how does he wants to understand the splat operator by using printting a list without spaces?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Because he doesn't understand `print` **_or_** splatting.  It's an XY problem in this one imo

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters, answers your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get that result because `print` automatically puts spaces between the passed arguments. You need to modify the `sep` parameter to prevent the `sep`aration spaces from being inserted:

```
print(*word, sep="")  # No implicit separation space
stackoverflow
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Does spat operator return some list again or what?

Comment: It simply unpacks the container.

Comment: @PavelAntspovich `print(*[1, 2, 3])` becomes `print(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the separator you want, in your case:

```
print(*word, sep="")
```

or do:

```
print(''.join(word))
```